# s3 bucket public access to only certain objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, access-control

I'm trying to configure an S3 bucket such that all objects are private except certain objects. I'm using a bucket policy like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::foo/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/public": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And then, of course, tagging certain objects as "public:true". When I add this bucket policy but do nothing else then all objects are available publically whether they've been tagged that way or not. I've tried different combinations on the "Block public access" screen but I either get everything allowed or everything denied. And then there's the Access Control List screen which I haven't done anything with:

[image: screen shot of Access Control List screen]

I also haven't done anything inside IAM. I'm guessing this disconnect is that I don't know how all these different methods of access control interact. My use case seems pretty simple: deny all except certain objects. What's they best way to achieve that?

Comment: If you simply wish to make certain objects public, then you can change the ACL setting on the individual object (`Make public`). I suspect that your above attempt will not work because the conditions only check the contents of the request, not the properties of the object being fetched.

Answer (score 0):

your policy should work. I have checked it just now. It's working for me. Also it does not make the entire bucket public.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/public": "yes"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: When S3 console shows the words `public`, that does not mean that the entire bucket is public, it means at least some part of the bucket public.

It should work for me, not only its working for me, AWS docs gives it as an example as well:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/

Comment: updated my answer, what makes you think that the policy makes your entire bucket public.